# Confusion about type conversion when propagate error with question mark in Rust?

Tags: rust

When I was propagating error with question mark, I found error with different type works properly, code is shown like following:

```rust
struct Car {
    brand: String
}

impl From<String> for Car {
    fn from(brand: String) -> Self {
        Car { brand }
    }
}

fn bar() -> Result<Car, String> {
    Err(String::from("xxxx"))
}

fn f() -> Result<Car,Car> {
   let c= bar()?;
   Ok(Car::from(String::from("xxx")))
}
```

But when return error with different type directly as below code:

```rust
struct Car {
    brand: String
}

impl From<String> for Car {
    fn from(brand: String) -> Self {
        Car { brand }
    }
}

fn bar() -> Result<Car,String> {
    Err(String::from("xxxx"))
}

fn f() -> Result<Car,Car> {
   
   Err(String::from("xxx"))
}
```

The compiler complained about return type mismatch. What's the difference between return directly and question mark. Is there any implicit type conversion will be applied with question mark? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, question mark operator `?` [expands to](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std/result/question_mark.html) `return Err(From::from(err))`.

However your last example doesn't explicitly try to convert from `String` into `Car`, thus the error. In Rust the conversion can't happen implicitly

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the question mark operator (or `ErrorPropagationExpression`) does have an implicit type-conversion [built into it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-question-mark-operator):

> When applied to values of the Result<T, E> type, it propagates errors.
> If the value is Err(e), then it will return **Err(From::from(e))**
> from the enclosing function or closure. If applied to Ok(x), then it
> will unwrap the value to evaluate to x.

That is, is the error-type in a `Result`-context can be converted via `Into`/`From`, the type conversion happens implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

[Rust: The `?` operator](https://m4rw3r.github.io/rust-questionmark-operator) indicates that this example code:

```
File::create("foo.txt")?.write_all(b"Hello world!")
```

Is roughly transformed as:

```
match File::create("foo.txt") {
    Ok(t)  => t.write_all(b"Hello world!"),
    Err(e) => return Err(e.into()),
}
```

Notice that there is a `.into()` applied to the error, and if you modify your code as follows:

```
fn f() -> Result<Car,Car> {
   Err(String::from("xxx").into())
}
```

Then the compiler no longer complains: the value is converted to a `Car`.